# Segmentation fault when using CyaSSL Keygen

Tags: c, ssl, wolfssl

I'm trying to get the Keygen function of CyaSSL to work using the example in section 7.7 from here: http://www.yassl.com/yaSSL/Docs-cyassl-manual-7-keys-and-certificates.html

I'm using CyaSSL 3.2.0 with the --enable-keygen option, but couldn't get it working with 3.1.0 either.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cyassl/ctaocrypt/asn.h>
#include <cyassl/ctaocrypt/rsa.h>

int main() {
        RsaKey genKey;
        RNG rng;
        int ret;

        printf("%d\n",InitRng(&rng));
        printf("%d\n",InitRsaKey(&genKey, 0));
        ret = MakeRsaKey(&genKey, 1024, 65537, &rng);

        printf("ret: %d\n",ret);

        return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault in the line with InitRsaKey, presumably because of an invalid write or something.

Anyone got an idea where my issue may be? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good morning, please do not forget to include options.h header. This will ensure that you get the proper configuration settings in your project for example if you configure CyaSSL with --enable-keygen then view cyassl/options.h you will see the line `#undef CYASSL_KEY_GEN` followed by `#define CYASSL_KEY_GEN`. Also in your makefile do not forget to include the cyassl library. This can be accomplished using `-lcyassl` in your build line. See code below for reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cyassl/options.h> //pull in the define for CYASSL_KEY_GEN
#include <cyassl/ctaocrypt/asn.h>
#include <cyassl/ctaocrypt/rsa.h>

int main() {
        RsaKey genKey;
        RNG rng;
        int ret;

        printf("%d\n",InitRng(&rng));
        printf("%d\n",InitRsaKey(&genKey, 0));
        ret = MakeRsaKey(&genKey, 1024, 65537, &rng);

        printf("ret: %d\n",ret);

        return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
 CC=gcc       #you can use clang or other instead of gcc                                                                   
 CFLAGS=-Wall                                                                    
 LIBS=-lpthread -lcyassl #must have -lcyassl in makefile                                                         

 all: run                                                                        

 #NOTE: arrows denote a hard tab, replace them with hard tab in makefile                                                                             
 run: test.o                                                                     
 →→→→$(CC) -o $@ $(LIBS) $^ $(CFLAGS) #put $(LIBS) into build command                                            

 .PHONY: clean all                                                               

 clean:                                                                          
 →→→→rm -f *.o test.o run
```

Comment: Thanks! The #include <cyassl/options.h> seems to to the trick.

Comment: No problem. If you ever have any other questions don't hesitate to ask!